# Django Foreign key. Access in template

Tags: django

I learn Django ORM. How can I get **Photo** in my template?

```
def index(request):    
    animal = Animal.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('animal.html',
                              {'animal':animal,},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template:

```
{{ animal.name }}
{{ animal.photo.all }}
```

but this not working.

models:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images')
    animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to read the documentation on [following relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) to see how do you access related items.

In your case, each `animal` has a `photo_set` which is a way to get a list of all the photo objects belonging to that animal.

In your template, you would do:

```
{{ animal.name }}
{% for picture in animal.photo_set.all %}
   <img src="{{ picture.photo.url }}" />
{% endfor %}
```